# Bash script to automatically encrypt log files

Tags: bash, files, cron, password, encryption

I have some logs used as proof in GDPR privacy matters.
The application handles personal data and logs who's using it to do what.
The logs should not be read by anyone unless there's an ongoing abuse investigation.

How can i store these logs which will be rotated every day, in a safe encrypted way (locally)? I'm thinking of a root crontab job, but the password should not be in plain text. All suggestions are very appreciated.

```
$ ls -ltrh
-rw-r----- 1 appuser appuser  83K May 27 23:55 gdpr.log.2018-05-27
-rw-r----- 1 appuser appuser 905K May 28 23:55 gdpr.log.2018-05-28
-rw-r----- 1 appuser appuser 3.0M May 29 23:40 gdpr.log.2018-05-29
-rw-r----- 1 appuser appuser 462K May 30 09:49 gdpr.log
```

Comment: look at https://serverfault.com/questions/912417/how-to-setup-logrotate-with-gpg-to-encrypt-for-gdpr

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://serverfault.com/questions/912417/how-to-setup-logrotate-with-gpg-to-encrypt-for-gdpr has the solution

Comment: Have you considered encrypting/obfuscating only the private part, instead of the whole logs? For instance, obfuscating IP addresses.

Answer (score 4):

You could encrypt the files using a public key which lives on the server, which can only be decrypted using a private key which is not on the server. This way even if the server is compromised, the encrypted logs should still be safe.

Example:

Create a directory to work in and create a new public and private key pair:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/1
$ cd /tmp/1
$ ssh-keygen -f key
$ ls
key
key.pub
```

Convert the public key to `pem` format:

```
$ openssl rsa -in key -pubout > key.pub.pem
```

Create a test file, called `file`, with the contents `hello`:

```
$ echo hello > file
```

Encrypt the file using the `pem` format public key and write the output to a file called `encrypted`:

```
$ cat file | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey key.pub.pem > encrypted_file
```

Decrypt the file using the private key:

```
$ cat encrypted_file | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey key
hello
```

Obviously you would want to move the private key off of the server, and you could put the encrypting commands into a cronjob. Something like:

```
for file in /var/log/dir/*;do
    cat "${file}" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey /path/to/key.pub.pem > "${file}.encrypted" && rm "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone remotely familiar with the subject could probably ask a hundred questions to establish what would even be realistic framework for a solution. That said, have you considered full-disk encryption? It's really, *really* simple compared to the overhead of building any kind of automation or procedure, and is probably good enough to cover your liability (I am not a lawyer) unless you're remote rooted.

Comment: A major drawback of using full-disk encryption is that the server can't be (re-)started without an administrator being available to manually enter the password (I use it on my laptop but none of the servers I manage).

Comment: Also an attacker who has compromised the system or rouge admin would be able to copy the decrypted logs off of the system, despite the underline storage being encrypted.